# How to remove "as low as" Price

Tags: magento2, price, magento-2.0

All of a sudden, "as low as" prices started to appear on my Magento 2.0.2 site.

Where did they come from? How to I remove them?

Comment: i dont know about magento 2, but in magento 1, it is because of tier prices you gave when uploading products.

Comment: is it displaying in both listing & product page, also is for all products ?

Comment: Thanks for helping @BabyinMagento. Actually as I looked through the site just now, it is only appearing on 1 product. So happens to be the last Configurable Product I was publishing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comments, `As low as text` will display only if you gave `Tier Prices` for your products. you can check those under section Prices > Tier Prices

[image]