# How can I remove "As low as" in Magento 2.2.4

Tags: price, magento2.2.4, product-prices

Since the upgrade from 2.2.3 to 2.2.4,  I got new function next to the price of each product. Which is: **As low as**.

How can I remove it? I can't find and option in Admin panel to switch it off.
Any idea how can I disable/remove it?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have few prieces per product. Did you read this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113186/how-to-remove-as-low-as-price ?

Comment: I have different colours for each product with the same price. also some sizes. but always one price for each product. so special price.

Comment: I added answer. I cannot add css code on third option, because I don't see this on my store. If you send me your url I will updated my answer.

Comment: @Greay, That means that any special price for that product, check for this and remove the special price. Or check for tier price.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Helpfull comand to check where we can find 'As low as'

```
grep -rnw '/var/www/html/your magento-directory' -e 'As low as'
```

You can use one of this three methods:

1. Rewrite final_price.phtml 
   Just copy

   vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml

to:

```
app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Catalog/product/price/final_price.phtml
```

and remove this line:

```
'display_label'     => __('As low as'),
```

2. Edit your translation, find line As low as
   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/i18n/en_US.csv (find your file with language)

'As low as' '(empty)'

3. find class with firebug and add display: none;

Comment: Thank you dear!
I searched by 
grep -rnw '/var/www/html/your magento-directory' -e 'As low as'
And I found it!

Comment: This command helped me loads of time in Magento. Remember it's recognizing capitol letters.

Comment: yes sure! thanx again!

Comment: Just execute `grep -iR "as low as"` from your root directory

Comment: The colon : remains so after removing As low as: $price I get :$price

How do I remove the remaining colon in css?

Answer (score 4):

In the last version of magento (2.3), the template that holds the final price is:

`your-magento-directory/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml`

to override it, you need to create a file in:

`app/design/frontend/<YOUR_VENDOR>/<YOUR_THEME>/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml`

Hope it helps.

Comment: You wrote about Configurable Products, nothing change in that matter anyway.

Comment: That's the template I override in order to do that

Comment: Yes like point 1, but you make overwrite of configurable product.

Comment: I finally understood. You were absolutely right, I haven't see there is more than one template for displaying price info. Thanks

Comment: For configurable products override this file . Good Answer

Answer (score 0):

in magento2 after creating configurable product the price is getting disable and its showing as low as