# Disable "As low as" from catalog and product page on Magento2.4.3

Tags: configurable-product, price, magento2.4.3

I want to disable "As low as" on product price.

First, I have try to change string label to empty in "Magento_Catalog/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php"

`'display_label'     => __(''),`

but, the text is still there.

Second, I try to remove these line

```
<?php if ($block->showMinimalPrice()) :?>
<?php if ($block->getUseLinkForAsLowAs()) :?>
    <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getSaleableItem()->getProductUrl()) ?>" class="minimal-price-link">
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->renderAmountMinimal() ?>
    </a>
<?php else :?>
    <span class="minimal-price-link">
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->renderAmountMinimal() ?>
    </span>
<?php endif?>
```

in "module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml"
but, nothing change.

I also delete the code from second method in "module-configurable-product/view/base/templates/product/price" too. but, still no luck.

I want to know that why it's not working and how to disable it.

Comment: Hi, Can you please following below link for your answer and I hope it's help full.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/232413/3723

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to create translation file and add the following entry.

> "As low as",""

You can read more on translation at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html